# Что такое mongodb? Чем отличается от mysql? Стоит ли использовать?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, mongodb

Недавно, услышал про mongodb и интересно что это такое, замена ли это mysql. Знаю mysql и хотел бы знать имеет ли смысл разобратся с mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB):

> MongoDB — документоориентированная система управления базами данных с открытым исходным кодом, не требующая описания схемы таблиц. Классифицирована как NoSQL, использует JSON-подобные документы и схему базы данных.

Т.е. это не замена и не полный аналог для `MySQL`. Это тоже БД, но информация там хранится по другому. У другого способа есть как преимущества, так и недостатки. Используют разные подходы в разных задачах. Ищите информацию по областям применения NoSQL БД и решайте надо ли оно вам.

---

Вот ещё статья с хабра как раз по теме: [MySQL и MongoDB — когда и что лучше использовать](https://habr.com/ru/post/322532/)